# Why is an authentication file accepted in the config file and not on the command line?

Tags: linux, openvpn, linux-networking

I connect to a VPN server which requires authentication via

```
/usr/sbin/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/server.ovpn
```

This prompts me for a login/password (= OK).

I added the login and password to a file and updated the `/etc/openvpn/server.ovpn` configuration with

```
auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/auth.txt
```

I am not prompted for the password anymore (= OK).

I wanted to provide the authentication credentials from the command line instead of sourcing them from the config file:

```
/usr/sbin/openvpn --auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/auth.txt --config /etc/openvpn/server.ovpn
```

**This time, I am prompted for credentials. Why is it so?**

The credentials file is the same, as well as the config (except for the `auth-user-pass` line which I removed for the last test).

The OpenVPN version is `2.3.10` and it was compiled with `enable_password_save=yes` (which must be the case since providing the credentials via the config file works, the package is installed from the standard Ubuntu repository)

Answer (score 11):

You have to change position of parameters, --auth-user-pass should be passed after --config parameter like this:

```
sudo openvpn --config "$HOME/your_file.ovpn" --auth-user-pass "$HOME/auth.txt"
```

Comment: Please explain, why the order of command line parameters matters, if possible. Interesting.

Comment: This is why Powershell is better (ducks head and runs for cover)

Comment: In all likelihood, `auth-user-pass` line in the config file overrides the command line option if that came first.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your OpenVPN user is able to access the auth file (otherwise referencing from the config file would have failed).

But just to be sure: is the user you start the OpenVPN connection allowed to read it?

Comment: Yes, both calls are made as `root` and the file is visible to `root`